# Loading Hive Data into Oracle Db

Tags: oracle11g, hive, mapping

I need to mapping a Hive table into a Oracle Db using Odi 11.1.1.6.0 .

I create physical and logical schema of the two technology. (connection test is ok)
I have a physical and logical odi agent that use Http and port 20910. (connection test is ok)

I used RKM for the reverse engineering of the two tables (tables Hive and the corresponding Oracle table with the same fields).

After that, I create a project with an interface to test the mapping. 
I use drag and drop for the source Hive table and the Target Oracle Table.
After that, I use drag and drop of each field of Hive table to the corresponding oracle table.
The dimension/type of each field of the two tables are the same.
I control the Flow of interface and this use only IKM File-Hive to Oracle (OLH).

When I start the interface, the session starting but there is this error:

```
ODI-1226: Step Hive_to_Oracle_test fails after 1 attempt(s).
ODI-1240: Flow Hive_to_Oracle_test fails while performing a Integration operation. This flow loads target table TEST_TABLE.
Caused By: com.sunopsis.dwg.function.SnpsFunctionBaseException: ODI-30038: OS command returned 4.
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.tools.OSCommand.actionExecute(OSCommand.java:294)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.function.SnpsFunctionBase.execute(SnpsFunctionBase.java:276)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.execIntegratedFunction(SnpSessTaskSql.java:3437)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.executeOdiCommand(SnpSessTaskSql.java:1509)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.OdiCommandExecutor.execute(OdiCommandExecutor.java:44)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.cmd.OdiCommandExecutor.execute(OdiCommandExecutor.java:1)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.TaskExecutionHandler.handleTask(TaskExecutionHandler.java:50)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.processTask(SnpSessTaskSql.java:2913)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessTaskSql.treatTask(SnpSessTaskSql.java:2625)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessStep.treatAttachedTasks(SnpSessStep.java:558)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSessStep.treatSessStep(SnpSessStep.java:464)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpSession.treatSession(SnpSession.java:2093)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$2.doAction(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:366)
    at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:216)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.doProcessStartSessTask(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:300)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.access$0(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:292)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$StartSessTask.doExecute(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:855)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.task.AgentTask.execute(AgentTask.java:126)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.support.DefaultAgentTaskExecutor$2.run(DefaultAgentTaskExecutor.java:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

`hive_to_oracle_test` is my interface,`TEST_TABLE` is my oracle table.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SQOOP check https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/con/Quest+Data+Connectors. You can also look into ORAOOP check http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/adapters/oraoopuserguide.pdf for more detials. Both of this could be used for data transfer from hive to oracle database.

Comment: i have to use ODI for this.